# Error in VAR: Different row size of y and exogen

Tags: r, var

I am attempting a VAR model in R with an exogenous variable on:

```
vndata <- read.csv("vndata.txt", sep="")
names(vndata)
da <- data.frame(vndata[2:dim(vndata),])

# STOCK PRICE MODEL
y <- da[, c("irate", "stockp", "mrate", "frate")]
x <- data.frame(da[, c("cdi")])

library("vars")
VARselect(y, lag.max = 8,exogen = x)
var1 <- restrict(VAR(y, p = 2,exogen = x),method = c("ser"),thresh = 1.56)
```

Then, I want to plot the impulse response function:

```
plot(irf(var1, impulse = c("irate"), response = c("frate"), boot = T,
cumulative = FALSE,n.ahead = 20))
```

however, it produces the warning:

```
Error in VAR(y = ysampled, p = 2, exogen = x) :   
Different row size of y and exogen.
```

I can not figure what happen. I have use `dim()` to make sure that `y` and `x` have the same row size.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it worked for me:

```
.GlobalEnv$exogen <- x 
VARselect(y, lag.max = 8,exogen = .GlobalEnv$exogen)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.